# Testing an Angular dialog window which is injected outside of debug element

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine

I am using an [Angular material dialog window](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

In my test I am triggering the modal window. But it's placing the modal window outside of the debug element. In the browser it looks like this:

[image]

The div with the `id="root1"` is the debug element. The div with the class `cdk-overlay-container` is the modal I would like to assert.

How do I do that if it's outside of the debug element?

For example I would like to get the modal as a debug element. And then test if a correct title is shown by:

```
let modal = ??;
expect(modal.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement.innerText).toBe('My Title')`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `document` object itself.

```
let modal = document.querySelector('.cdk-overlay-container');
let title = modal.querySelector('h1');
expect(title.innerText).toContain('My Title');
```

Comment: I like that this gives you the original DOM element. In your experience, is using the document a better alternative then using a custom fractory? I am wondering why the author of the article in my answer would go through the trouble of using a factory.

Comment: Interesting. Try doing it the article way. I say this because for document to work, you have to be doing your unit tests in a browser. Some projects may use jest or another testing framework that uses `jsdom` and `document.querySelector(..)` will return undefined because there will be nothing in the browser dom (there is no browser, tests are running in the terminal).

Comment: Good one. Then it would perhaps actually be a good idea to use the DOM since that will mimic a user's environment more closely. Jest uses jsdom indeed and document.querySelector would return something: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Found [this article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2018/02/testing-angular-material-dialog-templates/) explaining you could add a provider with a factory to get the overlayContainer:

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

//... 

  let overlayContainerElement: HTMLElement;

  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
      {
        provide: OverlayContainer,
        useFactory: () => {
          overlayContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
          return { getContainerElement: () => overlayContainerElement };
        }
      }
   ]
// ...
```

Now when I use `overlayContainerElement` I get a div with the inner contents of the original div with the class 'cdk-overlay-container'.

Not sure how to use the `getContainerElement` yet..